# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild') at TooltipContent.dispose on echart

Tags: angular, charts, javascript-objects, echarts

I am setting my option data dynamically for echart(pie). I used this to set option dynamically

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chartId'));
myChart.setOption(this.chartOption , true)
```

I am getting an error  on the tooltip dispose  while routing to another page from this page

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
> at TooltipContent.dispose (TooltipContent.js:352:24)
> [image]

Here is my option:

```
 chartOption = {

    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item'
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Topics',
        type: 'pie',
        data: [],
        color: ["#378AFF", "#FFA32F", "#F54F52", "#3D0C11", "#9552ea", "#93F03B", "#FF2E7E", "#7AC142", "#127C56", "#1B5583"],
        emphasis: {
          itemStyle: {
            shadowBlur: 10,
            shadowOffsetX: 0,
            shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };
```

I already used merge but on my case it's not working

```
[merge]="dynamicData" in html
this.dynamicData = { ... this.chartOption }; in ts file
```

I am expecting to  change the chart data and options based on my request

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in the [official echarts editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple)? Otherwise i suspect its an issue with angular.

Comment: I am getting while navigation so, i think i am not able to generate on offical echart

Thanks!

Comment: Missed the navigation part while reading, my bad

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your time

Answer (score -1):

you have to dispose the chart instance before navigation.

```
// Before navigating to another page, dispose of the ECharts instance
myChart.dispose();

// Navigate to the new page
// ...
```

Comment: Can i dispose my chart after immediately setting the option ?

Comment: before u navigate to another page, U have to ensure that any event listeners and components are properly cleaned up before navigation

Comment: I tried to dispose of my object in  onDestroy my current component but it generated an error before  the current component is destroy

Comment: It gives an error only on the tooltip part If i comment tooltip from option it works properly